# std::map without parent pointers?

Tags: c++, c++17

libstdc++, as an example, implements std::map using a red-black binary tree with parent pointers in the nodes.  This means that iterators can just be pointers to a node.

Is it possible for a standard library to implement std::map without storing parent pointers in the nodes?  I think this would mean that iterators would need to contain a stack of parent pointers, and as such would need to dynamically allocate a logarithmic amount of memory.  Would this violate standard performance constraints on iterators?  Would not having parent pointers violate any other performance contraints on the rest of the interface?

What about the new node stuff/interface in C++17?

Comment: Can I know the reason of not storing parent pointers in iterators and rather storing original data?

Comment: @MayankJain: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They may not do so. `std::map` guarantees that removing a key-value pair from it won't invalidate any iterators other than to the pair being removed.

If iterators will store a stack of parents, and a parent is removed, that will invalidate those iterators as well. And the guarantee will no longer hold.

Comment: Good observation! Note that it is also forbidden by the time complexity as the OP suggested – copying an iterator is required to be O(1) amortized ([iterator.requirements.general/10] in N4659).

Comment: @ArneVogel - That should be an answer. Not a comment to mine :)

Comment: Sorry for the a bit late reply… I had second thoughts about this, because while a `std::stack` (whether based on `std::deque` or `std::vector`) indeed cannot be used, it is probably allowed to implement this stack in the same manner as a list in Haskell. Briefly, these are based on immutable, reference counted nodes, similar to copy-on-write, so `top()`, `push()`, `pop()` and copying (to use stack terminology) are all O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Possibly :-) Is it a good idea? Almost certainly not. *Most* things are possible, if you throw more storage or speed at them :-)

In terms of just getting rid of the parent pointers, you *could,* for example, maintain within the map a monotonic value that is incremented each time the map structure is changed. In essence, it's a version identifier of the map structure. So, adding or deleting elements in the map increments this value, while merely changing the data within the map does not.

The iterator would then contain:

- a pointer to the map itself (to get the current version);
- the stack of pointers; and
- the version matching the last time the stack above was created.

The idea would basically be to, before doing anything with the iterator, detect when the map version is different to the iterator one and, if it is, rebuild the stack and update the iterator version before carrying on with whatever operation you're trying to perform.

Now, while that makes it possible to iterate without parent pointers, it unfortunately violates some other requirements of iterators, such as being able to action them in constant time. *Anything* that has to rebuild a data structure, based on the data within the map, will violate that restriction.

In any case, there's no way anyone in their right mind would *implement* such a horrid scheme when it's far simpler to have parent pointers, but the intent here is simply to show that it's *possible.*

Hence my advice would be to just stick with the parent pointers. The use of such parent pointers makes the process of finding the next/previous element a rather simple one, based *only* the current item in the iterator.

Comment: Ah, the fundamental theorem of storage and speed(TM) :)